# Xbox One controller not working on Ubuntu kernel 4.3.3

Tags: kernel, games, steam, gamepad

Before anything else, yes I have read most of the other threads on the site about Xbox One controllers. They have not helped. I have my Xbox One Controller on Ubuntu 14.04 with linux kernel 4.3.3 and I plug it in through USB because it is the stock one that is by default wireless but plugging it in works when I use Manjaro Linux. I have installed Antimicro controller mapper, xboxdrv package, joystick package and other stuff like that and I cant get anything to map, or the controller to work at all with any of my Steam games. Has anyone figured this out and can help me? I would love it!

Thanks, Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and kernal 4.2, but ran across [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/3ornmj/xbox_one_controller_not_detected_in_handful_of/):

> Btw, it may be an issue with the newer Xbox One controller model not in the upstream 4.2 and 4.3 kernels: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steamos_kernel/commit/45a23472199e21c710fc3bc5e6f0246ebcfb6d76
>
> Support is in the SteamOS kernel though and that PPA I mentioned.

That states the Xbox one controller support has not been carried upstream past 4.1 (so 4.2 and 4.3 would be non-functional).

Hope it helps!