# Wired Xbox One controller

Tags: kernel, gamepad

When I plug in an Xbox One controller either the whole system freezes or nothing happens. I read somewhere that the controllers are supported from kernel 3.17. How can I get the controller to work so I can play FF7 on steam?

```
uname -a
Linux Otur 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

I run X11 with fluxbox and compton if that has anything to do with anything at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get an XBOX 360 controller working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working)

Comment: & http://askubuntu.com/questions/717935/xbox-one-controller-not-working-on-ubuntu-kernel-4-3-3/737438#737438